# Processing arbitrary data: inherit and override base methods or provide callbacks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, architecture

I'm writing a Python class, let's call it `CSVProcessor`. Its purpose is the following:

1. extract data from a CSV file
2. process that data in an arbitrary way
3. update a database with the freshly processed data

Now it sounds like this is way too much for one class but it's already relying on high-level components for steps 1 and 3, so I only need to focus on step 2.
I also established the following:

- the data extracted in step 1 would be stored in a list
- every single element of that list needs to be processed individually and independently of one another by step 2
- the processed data needs to come out of step 2 as a list in order for step 3 to be continued

It's not a hard problem, Python is amazingly flexible and in fact, I already found two solutions but I'm wondering which are the side effects of each (if any). Basically, which should be preferred over the other and why.

### Solution 1

During runtime, my class `CSVProcessor` accepts in a function object, and uses it in step 2 to process every single element output by step 1. It simply aggregates the results from that function in an array and carries on with step 3.
Sample code (outrageously simplified but gives an idea):

```
class CSVProcessor:
    ...
    def step_1(self):
        self.data = self.extract_data_from_CSV()

    def step_2(self, processing_function):
        for element in self.data:
            element = processing_function(element)

    def step_3(self):
        self.update_database(self.data)
```

Usage:

```
csv_proc = CSVProcessor()
csv_proc.step_1()
csv_proc.step_2(my_custom_function)         # my_custom_function would defined elsewhere
csv_proc.step_3()
```

### Solution 2

My class `CSVProcessor` defines an "abstract method" whose purpose is to process single elements in a concrete implementation of the class. Before runtime, `CSVProcessor` is inherited from by a new class, and its abstract method is overridden to process the elements.

```
class CSVProcessor:
    ...
    def step_1(self):
        self.data = self.extract_data_from_CSV()

    def processing_function(self, element): # Abstract method to be overridden 
        pass

    def step_2(self):
        for element in self.data:
            element = self.processing_function(element)

    def step_3(self):
        self.update_database(self.data)
```

Usage:

```
class ConcreteCSVProcessor:
    def processing_function(self, element): # Here it gets overridden
        # Do actual stuff
        # Blah blah blah

csv_proc = ConcreteCSVProcessor()
csv_proc.step_1()
csv_proc.step_2()                           # No need to pass anything!
csv_proc.step_3()
```

In hindsight these two solutions share quite the same workflow, my question is more like "where should the data processing function reside in?".
In C++ I'd obviously have gone with the second solution but both ways in Python are just as easy to implement and I don't really see a noticeable difference in them apart from what I mentioned above.

And today there's also such a thing as considering one's ways of doing things more or less Pythonic... :p

Comment: I believe you are asking for the "D" In solid, I would tend to an even different solution, as to implement some interface that deals with processing, so you call the abstraction, e.g. self.processor.processing_function(self.data), and then as to WHO or WHAT processor is depends on the implementation it makes of the abstract interface processor.If that makes sense. also DON'T do this 
        for element in self.data: element = self.processing_function(element), doself.data = [self.processing_function(element) for element in self.data], that way it will only overwrite once and not if it fails

Comment: I see, thanks for the hints! As for the syntax of the for loop, the example was really simplified. In my actual code, I can't afford the callbacks to fail silently because if they fail, the element should not stick to its original value. But it's good to know that it has this effect!